# Can we install Galera cluster on shared storage

Tags: mariadb

Need some information
Can we install 3 node mariadb galera cluster on shared storage

Comment: Are you proposing putting the data of the 3 nodes on a single disk?  What will the benefits of Galera?

Answer (score 1):

Mariadb isn't a stored storage database. You might be able to put three copies on a shared storage and implement your own faster sst because of it.

You will however have a single point of failure that Galera works to avoid by keeping copies of the entire dataset.

If you want to keep your shared storage, maybe there's another way (e.g.: k8s, [Packermaker](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/)) to start up a MariaDB instance on another node when your sure the previous node was down.